# Exact dimensions through imageMagic and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, rmagick

So I know how both `imageMagik` and `carrierwave` work but the question is can they do exact resize of image. I tried with `process resize_to_fit: [100, 100]` and uploaded a `800*200` image which resulted in `100*27` instead of `100*100`. `resize_to_fill` does it but crops the image which should not be. Is there any way to resize to exact width and height in `Ruby on Rails` using the `carrierwave` .

Comment: So you don't want to retain the original proportions?

Comment: @NMPennypacker yes even then too

Comment: `resize_to_fit` will take the largest dimension and scale down the smallest accordingly. It's impossible to make a 800*200 image into a 100*100 image without losing some of the image, or adding whitespace...

Comment: @NMPennypacker my focus is on dimension not on quality as i mentions in my comment too

Comment: If your input image has one aspect ratio and the desired output has another then the only way to achieve the desired output is to distort the image to the new aspect ratio, thereby filling it out. Is that really what you want. Imagemagick can do that using the "!" character as -resize "100x100!". Most people would resize keeping the aspect ratio, but scale the smaller dimension, so that the larger dimension is larger than 100. Then center crop the image. This is done in Imagemagick with -resize "100x100^". Alternately, crop and pad the image using -gravity center -extent 100x100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

Carrierwave passes a block with [resize_to_fit](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L177-L179) and [resize_to_limit](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L146-L152) to the [`manipulate!`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L356) method to crop the image.

By changing this block, you can change the cropping/resizing. `Carrierwave` calls on [instance `Magick::Image`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L352) the method [`change_geometry`](http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#change_geometry) at this [line](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L147).

> The `change_geometry` method supports resizing a method by specifying constraints. For example, you can specify that the image should be resized such that the aspect ratio should be retained but the resulting image should be no larger than 640 pixels wide and 480 pixels tall.
>
> The argument may be either a [geometry string](http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/imusage.html#geometry) or a [Geometry object](https://rmagick.github.io/struct.html#Geometry). Change_geometry yields to the block, passing new width and height values based on the argument with respect to self. The return value is the return value of the block.

You need to pass a block to [`manipulate!`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L348) similar to the below example:

```
def resize_no_crop(width, height)
  width = dimension_from width
  height = dimension_from height
  manipulate! do |img|
      # change the below geometry object to achieve your effect
      # geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(width, height, 0, 0,    Magick::GreaterGeometry)
      new_img = img.change_geometry(geometry) do |new_width, new_height|
      img.resize(new_width, new_height)
    end
    destroy_image(img)
    new_img = yield(new_img) if block_given?
    new_img
  end
end
```

Set the `geometry` object as per your desires

```
geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(width, height, 0, 0, !)
```

as I read in the docs, the last parameters `!` has the following effect

> `!`    Use this flag when you want to force the new image to have exactly the size specified by the the width and height attributes.

[`ImageMagick` command line tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) and [Rmagick](https://rmagick.github.io/) api docs provide more information.

### Explanation

`Carrierwave` uses `miniMagick` [to perform the resizing process](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb#L67).

> The ImageProcessing gem uses MiniMagick, a mini replacement for RMagick that uses ImageMagick command-line tools, to build a "convert" command that performs the processing.

This is how the `resize_to_limit` method works, it may help you building your own method using the `Rmagick` and `ImageMagick` command line tools.

```
module MiniMagick
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    require "image_processing/mini_magick"
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def convert(format)
      process :convert => format
    end

    def resize_to_limit(width, height)
      process :resize_to_limit => [width, height]
    end
  end
end
```

The `method` manipulates the images using the [`ImageMagick` command line tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) and [Rmagick](https://rmagick.github.io/). You can visit the above websites to read their documentation.

As you can read below [`resize_to_limit`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L142) manipulates the image by creating a new instance of [`Magick::Geometry`](https://rmagick.github.io/struct.html#Geometry) and passing a `width`,`height`, `x,y` and `flag`

```
def resize_to_limit(width, height)
  width = dimension_from width
  height = dimension_from height
  manipulate! do |img|
     # Read The Explanation below
  end
end
```

`Carrierwave` created their own [`manipulate!` method](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L348) which will [iterate with the yield statement and crop/resize the image](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L146-L152)

```
  image.each_with_index do |frame, index|
    frame = yield(*[frame, index, options].take(block.arity)) if block_given?
    frames << frame if frame
  end
```

The method `each_with_index` will iterate [between `manipulate! do ... end`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L146-L152) with the yield statement.

`*[frame, index, options].take(block.arity)`, `.take(block.arity)` will pass only [`frame`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L352) as it is called [with only one parameter](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/664e99e7ad2d6f1e0410c99eeba82ee0afd2fb11/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb#L145).

The `frame` variable will equal the `new_image` returned.

```
geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(width, height, 0, 0, Magick::GreaterGeometry)
new_img = img.change_geometry(geometry) do |new_width, new_height|
  img.resize(new_width, new_height)
end
destroy_image(img)
new_img = yield(new_img) if block_given?
new_img
```

You can read more about [Image::Magick class](https://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html) and [on rmagick.github.io](https://rmagick.github.io/) to better understand how the process of frame selection works.

Answer (score 0):

@ImranNaqvi it's just a version of your image, and displaying it in the html view is another story, right? So you still render `<img src="your_img_100_27_url" width="100" height="100">` sorry if i misunderstood you.

Comment: yes, i am sure that you didn't understand the question correctly. I am not talking about rendering if this dimension. but actual xropping of image